# Docker build failing - Unable to locate package

Tags: ruby, docker, dockerfile

Trying to add jemalloc to ruby, on my project, but failing on this line

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libjemalloc1 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.6.5-slim-buster


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libjemalloc1 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.1
```

Getting a `E: Unable to locate package libjemalloc1` Error.

Is there a way for me to verify if the package actually exists?

Any workaround available?

Comment: You can always do an `apt search <package_name>`, it even supports regex. Tried it from the base image and found `libjemalloc2` but not `libjemalloc1`.

Comment: thanks a lot @frippe! running `apt search` gave me
- libjemalloc-dev/oldstable 5.1.0-3 arm64
- libjemalloc2/oldstable 5.1.0-3 arm64

really looking for v 3.x though on libjemalloc1

does that mean, its not available for the ruby version I am using, or not available at all? would you know?

Comment: You can search for packages [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=jemalloc&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). 3.x seems to still be there, but not in the buster repo. If manually adding a source and pulling the desired version doesn't work for you, you could always build it from source

Comment: by adding a source, you mean running a 'add-apt-repository' command?

Comment: Yeah, either that or adding it under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Answer (score 1):

Please use libjemalloc2

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libjemalloc2 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2
```

Comment: Hi, can you add some explanation, or docs? Code-only answers will not help much others